# Converting a dominant weight of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ to $\mathfrak{sl}_n$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

The rank of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is $n-1$, so given a dominant $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ weight $(d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n)$ such that $d_1 \geq d_2 \geq \dots \geq d_n$, the corresponding weight for $\mathfrak{sl}_n \subset \mathfrak{gl}_n$ should be $(d_1 - d_2, d_2-d_3, \dots, d_{n-1}-d_n)$. But this does not satisfy the same condition $d_1-d_2 \geq d_2-d_3 \geq \dots$, take for example the $\mathfrak{gl}_3$ weight $(1,1,0)$.

I ask this because in a theorem of Chriss-Ginzburg 4.2.3, we are given that a simple $\mathfrak{sl}_n$-module is given an associated highest weight $(d_1 \geq d_2 \cdots \geq d_n)$, which I am sure is a typo.

However, even if it is, we are not guaranteed the highest weight for $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. So what do the authors mean here?

Edit 1: To make clear my understanding, a basis of the weight space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is given by the functionals $\epsilon_i : \mathfrak{h} \to \mathbb{C}, 1 \leq i \leq n$ which sends the diagonal matrix to its $i$-th entry. A basis of the weight space of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is given by the functionals
$$
\varpi_i := \epsilon_i - \frac{1}{n}(\epsilon_1 + \dots + \epsilon_n), 1 \leq i \leq n-1.
$$

It is not clear to me how the $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ weight $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ can be converted to the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ weight $(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\varpi_1$.

Edit 2: Also, the CSA $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{sl}_n$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{h}_0 \subset \mathfrak{gl}_n$. Then $\mathfrak{h}^* = \mathfrak{h}_0^* / \mathfrak{h}^\perp$. However it is not clear to me that $\mathfrak{h}^\perp = \{\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}_0^* : \lambda(\mathfrak{h}) = 0\}$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}(\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_n)$. Clearly the latter is included in the former, but showing the converse is not easy for me. I have that $$\mathfrak{h}^\perp = \{\sum_i \lambda_i \epsilon_i : \sum_i \lambda_i \epsilon_i(h) = 0 \text{ for all } h \in \mathfrak{h}\},$$ but all this says is that $$\lambda_1h_1 + \dots + \lambda_nh_n = 0,$$ and (even when trying to use that $h_1 + \dots + h_n = 0$ for all $h \in \mathfrak{h}$) there is no way to conclude that $\lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_n$ from this condition.

Comment: As for weight spaces:carefully write down the Cartan subalgebras and weight spaces of gl and sl, paying close attention to what should be duals and what should not. I think the fundamental weights you have written _work_ in that they describe the same sort of thing as the quotient space I wrote down, but they’re not quite _natural_ since you don’t know how to take a gln weight and send it to an sln weight (which is very in the quotient perspective). Think about how these algebras work, you should always be able to restrict a gln weight to an sln weight, and there should be no choice involved.

Comment: I recall doing a fairly detailed write-up of this in my thesis, though from the perspective of algebraic groups. When I am on a computer I will see if I can find an online version of it.

Comment: I have edited the question to include where I am stuck in working out why the weight space of sln is a quotient of gln, as per suggestion by @Joppy.

Comment: An online version of my thesis can be found at https://data.math.au.dk/publications/phd/2014/math-phd-2014-tk.pdf. The relevant part is in Chapter 4, but it might be a bit too much work to translate from the language of algebraic groups to be of much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation for $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ weights and $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ weights you are using is different. It is clearer if we write things in terms of a basis.

The weight space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is $\mathbb{C}\{\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n\}$, where $\epsilon_i \colon \mathfrak{gl}_n \to \mathbb{C}$ is the linear map taking a diagonal matrix $D$ to the entry $D_{ii}$. A weight $\lambda = \lambda_1 \epsilon_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n \epsilon_n$ is conventionally written $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$. In this post I will write $\lambda = \epsilon(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ so we don't get confused. The condition that $\lambda$ is *dominant* is equivalent to $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$.

The weight space of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is $\mathbb{C}\{\epsilon_1, \cdots, \epsilon_n\} / \mathbb{C}(\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_n)$, a quotient space. So in terms of the $\epsilon$ labelling, there are many weights of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ that descend to the same $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ weight, for example when $n = 3$, the weights $\epsilon(3, 2, 1)$ and $\epsilon(4, 3, 2)$ become the same $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ weight.

The $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ weight space is $(n - 1)$-dimensional, and it has a basis given by the *fundamental weights* $\varpi_1, \ldots, \varpi_{n-1}$ where $\varpi_i = \epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_i$ (I mean the image of this element inside the quotient). If you compute the change-of-basis inside the $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ weight space from the $\epsilon$ basis to the $\varpi$ basis, you will find that
$$ \epsilon(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) = \lambda_1 \epsilon_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n \epsilon_n \mapsto (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) \varpi_1 + \cdots + (\lambda_{n-1} - \lambda_n) \varpi_{n-1} = \varpi(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_{n-1} - \lambda_n).$$
So the $\mathfrak{gl}_3$ weight $\epsilon(3, 2, 1)$ becomes the $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ weight $\varpi(1, 1)$. If $\lambda = \varpi(d_1, \ldots, d_{n-1})$ is an $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ weight, the the condition for $\lambda$ to be dominant is simply $d_i \geq 0$.

So before writing a weight down as just a list of numbers, make sure you know what basis of the weight space you are working in.

Comment: I am not convinced from my own calculations for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ that this is the correct way to do it. If $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$ is a $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ weight, then I am getting two extra terms $\lambda_2\epsilon_1, -\lambda_3\epsilon_1$ that don't disappear when mapping to the quotient. If you could provide the calculation or point me to a source that does the calculation I think that would satisfactorily answer my question :)

Comment: @nhmwhhxx: what do you mean by “two extra terms” and disappearing? Can you give a concrete example? I don’t understand where those specific terms are coming from.

Comment: I've actually figured it out, thanks though. The terminology _fundamental weight_ is not something I am familiar with nor can find in my texts that I learned out of. Could you give a reference to that, as well as that the weight space of $sl$ is the quotient space? I am only a beginner in all of this, sorry for that.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx: Weight spaces and fundamental weights (and roots and simple roots) you can read about in any book on root systems or Lie theory. The weight space as a quotient space is because the diagonal subalgebra of sl is a subspace of gl, when taking dual spaces you get a quotient.

Comment: It's particularly the terminology of fundamental weights that I am worried about. I have not seen that before.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx Read something like Humphrey's _Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory_, particularly the parts about semisimple Lie algebras and root systems. So much of Chriss and Ginzburg will not make sense, or seem completely unmotivated, before you understand root systems, the terminology involved, and their associated Lie algebras. There is really no way around this, you should spend a few weeks learning this before moving on.

Comment: Looking through Humphreys again, there does not seem to be any mention of fundamental weights in the context of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, nor how the weight space is constructed as you did in your answer. I have already read on root systems and semisimple Lie algebras, but that does not cover the answer.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx There is no such thing as a fundamental weight for $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, since it is not semisimple. The fundamental weights are defined as being the basis dual to the simple coroots, and $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ has an $n$-dimensional Cartan but only $n - 1$ simple coroots.

Answer (score 4):

I will give an answer specifically on the relationship between the weight spaces of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. For this I will introduce some nonstandard notation: let $D_n$ be the vector space of diagonal $n \times n$ matrices (the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$), and $S_n \subseteq D_n$ be the vector space of traceless diagonal $n \times n$ matrices (the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$).

**Weights of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ restrict to weights of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$**: A weight of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is simply a linear map $\lambda \colon D_n \to \mathbb{C}$. Since $S_n \subseteq D_n$, we get a restricted map $\overline{\lambda} \colon S_n \to \mathbb{C}$ by composing the inclusion $S_n \hookrightarrow D_n$ with $\lambda$. We do not need to choose bases or anything to do this, this is simply restricting a linear function to a subspace.

**The weight space of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is a quotient of the weight space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$**: Using the restriction map above, we have a map of vector spaces
$$ \operatorname{Hom}(D_n, \mathbb{C}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(S_n, \mathbb{C}), \quad \lambda \mapsto \overline{\lambda}. $$
It is easy to see this map is surjective and that the dimension of the space on the right is $n - 1$, and hence there is a one-dimensional kernel. The trace function $\operatorname{tr} \colon D_n \to \mathbb{C}$ is nonzero and belongs to the kernel (since the trace function restricted to traceless matrices is zero), hence by the first isomorphism theorem we have
$$ \operatorname{Hom}(D_n, \mathbb{C}) / (\mathbb{C} \operatorname{tr}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(S_n, \mathbb{C}). $$

**A basis for the weight space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$:** Let $\epsilon_i \colon D_n \to \mathbb{C}$ be the linear map taking a diagonal matrix to its $(i, i)$ entry. Then $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n$ form a basis for the weight space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. Weights of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ are often written in two ways. The first is $\lambda = \lambda_1 \epsilon_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n \epsilon_n$ where the dominance condition is $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$. The second way is by defining $\varpi_i = \epsilon_1 + \cdots  + \epsilon_i$ and noting that $\varpi_1, \ldots, \varpi_n$ forms another basis for the weight space. The weight $\lambda = w_1 \varpi_1 + \cdots + w_n \varpi_n$ is dominant if and only if $w_i \geq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$. (The last coefficient $w_n$ can be freely varied and has no effect on the dominance of the weight. Note that $\varpi_n = \operatorname{tr}$). Some people call this second basis the "fundamental weight" basis of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ although that is an abuse of notation: it is a particular choice of basis which obeys the condition $\langle \varpi_i, \alpha_j^\vee \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ for all simple coroots $\alpha_j^\vee$ for $1 \leq j \leq n - 1$, but is in no way unique. It is very convenient though, as $\varpi_i$ is the highest weight of the $i$th wedge power of the standard representation.

**A basis for the weight space of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$:** For instance $\overline{\epsilon_1}, \ldots, \overline{\epsilon_{n-1}}$ would be a basis, as the weight space of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is $n-1$ dimensional, and these functions remain linearly independent when restricted to $S_n$. However this is a pretty arbitrary choice, rather than leaving out $\overline{\epsilon_n}$ I could have left out any one of the $\overline{\epsilon_i}$ from my list and obtained a basis of the weight space. What is convenient is that the weights $\overline{\varpi_i} = \overline{\epsilon_1} + \cdots + \overline{\epsilon_i}$ remain linearly independent (aside from $\varpi_n$ which gets sent to zero). These $n-1$ weights are *truly* the fundamental weight basis for $\mathfrak{sl}_n$.

**An example**: Consider the $\mathfrak{gl}_3$ weight $\lambda = 4 \epsilon_1 +  \epsilon_2 +  \epsilon_3$. This could also be expressed as $\lambda = 3 \varpi_1 + \varpi_3$. In the quotient, we have
$$\overline{\lambda} = 4 \overline{\epsilon_1} +  \overline{\epsilon_2} +  \overline{\epsilon_3} = 3 \overline{\epsilon_1} +  0\overline{\epsilon_2} +  0\overline{\epsilon_3} = 2 \overline{\epsilon_1} - \overline{\epsilon_2} -  \overline{\epsilon_3}.$$
(Note that many $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ weights map to $\overline{\lambda}$, such as $2 \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2 - \epsilon_3$). Using the fact that $\lambda = 3 \varpi_1 + \varpi_3$ we can also see that $\overline{\lambda} = 3 \overline{\varpi_1} + 0 \overline{\varpi_2}$ in the fundamental weight basis.

---

So that was quite long, and there is some fiddly stuff in dealing with weight spaces and different bases. (I think this is fine, in Lie theory there are a lot of related vector spaces and vectors and bases and it takes some time to get across them all). I think the basis you have written in your original post which involves $\frac{1}{n}$ is confusing the fundamental weights with the fundamental coweights, which is why it is unnatural: the *weights* of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ naturally restrict to weights of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, while the *coweights* of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ naturally embed into the coweights of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. The $\varpi_i$ you have written there clearly and naturally becomes a $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-thing, and this should only happen for coweights. There *should not* be a natural way of taking an $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ weight to a $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ weight.

Comment: Very nice summary.

Comment: Agreed, this is very nice. I have only one question - $\overline{\epsilon_1}, \dots, \overline{\epsilon_{n-1}}$ are a basis for the weight space of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, but obviously removing one of them no longer gives a basis for the latter. Do you just mean the basis of some random space? Otherwise it is not clear to me why it is 'natural' to use the $\overline{\varpi_i}$ basis instead (it is obvious why it is convenient though).

Comment: @nhmwhhxx They form a basis for that quotient space. As with any quotient space, you have the annoying (but necessary) fact that there are very few "natural" ways to choose a basis, you usually choose a linearly independent set in the space upstairs that descends to a basis in the quotient (such as $\epsilon_i$ for all but a single $i$). However, since $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, it posesses _canonical_ simple coroots $\alpha_i^\vee$ for $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$ which form a basis for the Cartan $S_n$. The dual basis to the $\alpha_i^\vee$ is precisely $\overline{\varpi_i}$.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx
I guess something that I just swept under the rug is that the simple coroots are not quite canonical until you choose a positive/simple system of roots, or equivalently a borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. The standard choice here is to choose the simple roots to be $\overline{\epsilon_i} - \overline{\epsilon_{i+1}}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$, which corresponds to choosing the Borel subalgebra to be the upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Yes, I understand that simple coroots depend on choice of simple roots. On the first part, maybe it would be helpful to edit and say "Omitting any one of $\epsilon_i$ in the weight space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ would still descend to a basis of the quotient space". Nevertheless, thank you very much for the assistance!

Comment: @nhmwhhxx Ah, I see why that wasn't so clear, sorry about that